# Aegir / drush alias issue: profiles specified at command line get forgotten

Tags: users, drush, installation, aegir

Note: Aegir is an installation / site management tool for drupal sites & platforms. See http://community.aegirproject.org/ for details.

This question may be down to an Aegir issue or a drush one; thoughts from either angle are welcome:

I've managed to create Aegir/drupal platforms via both the command line (see http://lists.aegirproject.org/pipermail/aegir/2011-January/000026.html) and web interface, and I can get sites to install with a selected profile through the web interface, but when I try to install a site via the command line it keeps resetting to the default profile. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

I create a site alias:

```
drush --uri='demo.c.didev.co.uk' provision-save '@site_demo.c.didev.co.uk' --context_type=site --platform='@platform_dennis_generic_20110316b' --profile='myprofile' --db_server='@server_localhost' --client_email='me@domain.com'
```

and it creates a valid alias file:

```
cat .drush/site_demo.c.didev.co.uk.alias.drushrc.php 
<?php $aliases['site_demo.c.didev.co.uk'] = array ( 
'context_type' => 'site', 
'platform' => '@platform_dennis_generic_20110316b', 
'server' => '@server_master', 'db_server' => '@server_localhost', 
'uri' => 'demo.c.didev.co.uk', 
'root' => '/var/aegir/platforms/dennis_generic_20110316b/', 
'site_path' => '/var/aegir/platforms/dennis_generic_20110316b//sites/demo.c.didev.co.uk', 
'site_enabled' => true, 
'language' => 'en', 
'client_email' => 'me@domain.com', 
'aliases' =>  array ( ), 
'redirection' => false, 
'profile' => 'myprofile', );
```

However, when I run "drush @hostmaster hosting-import @site_demo.c.didev.co.uk" it rewrites the alias file to "profile = default" and installs with the default profile!

Now, this is a pain but not a disaster as I can do the initial site creating via the web interface and it'll work, but I get apparently related errors when trying to migrate on the command line (per instructions at http://community.aegirproject.org/node/41) where it appears to not create an array of profiles and crashes (I'll post on that separately later) and wanted to rule out these problems before I tackle those.

So - am I doing something wrong, or is there just a bug?

Comment: can you do a normal 'drush si' using the profile?

Answer (score 3):

I tweeted this to Mig - he says:

> probably a bug. Workaround is to not hosting-import the site but re-verify the platform & let it autoimport site by itself

HTH! =)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.leveltendesign.com/blog/randall-knutson/ultimate-server-mercury-aegir) shows something akin to what you are doing. One interesting line in it is.

> Be sure to install the 3.3 version of
>   Drush as any newer versions will cause
>   problems with Aegir later (as I found
>   out the hard way)

That may be worth trying.